# How to fix React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h' file not found

Tags: react-native, build

I created new project by react-native `init`.

but I can not run it.

gave me error `React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h` file not found.

react-native `run-ios` at terminal in mac

Comment: please reinstall the node_modules and try to build

Comment: I believe this issue has to do with the newest react-native 0.60 update which now uses cocoapods by default. if you open your ios folder and run `pod update` then try your command again it should work. This seems to be because react-native init is not creating an xcworkspace.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: I am facing the same problem

Comment: in your Xcode project, general tab, section Deployment info, what iOS is defined? is it the same as the Podfile?

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because the necessary cocoapods are not installed in the Xcode project
This is how you fix it

- Navigate into your ios file in your terminal (cd > ios)
- Run the command: Pod install
- Navigate back to the root of your project and run it.

It should run just fine now. :)